# Angular 2 + routing + animations

Tags: animation, typescript, angular, dart, angular2-routing

I'm currently working on a project that uses the routing approach (not documentation yet for Dart):
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router-deprecated.html

And I wonder how could I control the transition between different views. I read about the CssAnimationBuilder, but there is no much documentation about this class.

Even though the question is related to the Dart environment, TypeScript and JavaScript programmers are welcome, since Dart is still a small group.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new router coming *again* and there is also new animation feature work in progress and it looks like it is about to be shipped (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr4IKlr9mhg) I think it's better to wait until these become available.

If you need or want a solution immediately I would create a custom `<router-outlet>` that adds the new component, before it removes the old one and adds/removes CSS classes as required to make it easy to apply animations.